# Puzzled by $\lim_{x \to +\infty} (\sqrt{x^2 + x} - x) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + x} + x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, asymptotics

In chapter 3, example 42 of [Mathematical Analysis, vol 1](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-48792-1), Zorich states that
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} (\sqrt{x^2 + x} - x)
= \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + x} + x}.
$$
This equivalence is not at all clear to me. Is it an error? I would love to see a derivation or justification.

Comment: Remove the limits. Multiply the lhs by its conjugate and simplify

Comment: $$y-x=\frac{y^2-x^2}{y+x}$$

Comment: whoops, that should have been obvious. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rationalise the numerator of the limit by multiplying both numerator and denominator by the conjugate of numerator.
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to \infty} (\sqrt{x^2 + x} - x)\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + x} + x}{\sqrt{x^2 + x} + x} &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\sqrt{x^2 + x} - x)(\sqrt{x^2 + x} + x)}{\sqrt{x^2 + x} + x}\\& =\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2 + x - x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + x} + x}\\& =\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + x} + x} \end{align}$$